# Composer outdated command doesn't show latest versions

Tags: php, symfony, docker-compose, composer-php

I am using Composer version 2.0.8, with Docker.

When I use the command `composer outdated -f json` inside a composer project, the field "latest", giving the latest version available for a library, is wrong. (https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#outdated)

Instead, the fields contains a version number that is not the latest version available (when i check on https://packagist.org/).

For example, the command says that the latest version for the bundle `twig/twig` is v1.42.5, while the version 3.3.0 is already out (https://packagist.org/packages/twig/twig)

Similarly with `symfony/symfony`, the command says that the latest version is v3.4.47

Anyone had this problem ?
Thank you very much for any answers

EDIT : For the tests i used this composer.json file : https://github.com/MathisLAURENT/Test/blob/master/a/very/long/path/to/source/composer.json
And i use Composer 2.0.8 inside a Docker container.

Comment: Never used it and just a stab in the dark, but could it be that the "latest" version takes your dependencies into account?!

Comment: Could you add your composer.json to your question?

Comment: Please share more details. Also, please explain how this is related to Docker or Symfony itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP version (5.5.2) of the composer.json is to old for the newer version of composer packages. If you upgrade the php version to 7.4 in the docker container and in the composer.json, it will install the newer versions of the packages.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, my php version in Docker was already in 7.4, i changed the line 58 of my composer file to version 7.4 and it worked fine.
I feel like it's wierd since composer outdated should be using an API to get the latest versions of the packages (imo) no matter the PHP version, but whatever